# Python - Get the value which Satisfies OR Truth Table out of two values

Tags: python

I have two objects which returns two values, lets say x1, x2. I just have to check whether the values exist or not and if exists it should return those, which is not None,False, 0.

This is just simple try, which is OK:

```
def get_valid_keys(x1, x2):
    """ """
    a = []
    if x1: a.append(x1)
    if x2: a.append(x2)
    return a
```

But I feel,there should be something in python which would return above variables instead of values with an efficient way:
like:

```
>>> x1, x2 = 0, 1
>>> x1 or x2
1     # It should return x2    
>>> x1, x2 = 1, 0
>>> x1 or x2
1    # It should return x1    
>>> x1, x2 = 0, 0
>>> x1 or x2
0    # It should return None     
>>> x1, x2 = 1, 1
>>> x1 or x2
1     # It should return x1, x2
```

Comment: Have you seen `filter()`?  https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter.  You can also do it using a list comprehension.

Comment: Python doesn't "know" the names of the references ("variables"). You can't simply return `'x1'` instead of `0`. You can't go back from `0` to the name or names that reference it.

Comment: @cdarke I believe OP wants to get the name of the reference, not its value.

Comment: @DeepSpace:  OK,  I misunderstood then.  He/she should be using a dictionary.

Comment: `x1` and `x2` are not values, they are references to their values.  A value can have many references to it - it can be known by many names.  The names "x1" and "x2" are not even in scope outside the function.  If you want a text name to be tied to a value then you should consider using a dictionary.

Comment: @DeepSpace: considering the `filter` solution has been accepted, I guess the OP did want the value after all!

Comment: @cdarke : Yes, It's true, Value was important to me. Thanks for suggestions about references. I have edited the post now to make it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weed out any zeroes:

```
filter(lambda x: x, [x1, x2])
```